# update query that Works directly in MYSQL but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using `mysqli` on PHP to run a query that sums a value to an existing value as follows. I've simplified the query for clarity, normally I use variables for the different values. Obviously the `OpenDBConnection` is a function that I wrote myself and works perfectly elsewhere in the same script.

```
$sql="update TBL_Stock set STOCK_Cost = STOCK_Cost + 9 WHERE PO_ID='PO.16.030128'";
$con = OpenDBConnection();
$con->query($sql);
```

Now, when I execute the query directly in MySQL (using MySQL Workbench) it works perfectly, and `9` is added to the current value of `STOCK_Cost`. However, on PHP nothing happens, and `9` isn't added to `STOCK_Cost`.

The strange thing is that the following php bit DOES work:

```
$sql="update TBL_Stock set STOCK_Cost = 9 WHERE PO_ID='PO.16.030128'";
$con = OpenDBConnection();
$con->query($sql);
```

Obviously it doesn't do what I want the code to do, but in the last script the value of `STOCK_Cost` is set to `9`.

So just adding changing the last bit to `STOCK_Cost = Stock_Cost + 9` ... and it stops working. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: `STOCK_Cost = Stock_Cost + 9` you are not putting correct column name. it should be `STOCK_Cost = STOCK_Cost + 9` and your final query will be :-  `$sql="update TBL_Stock set STOCK_Cost = STOCK_Cost + 9  WHERE PO_ID='PO.16.030128'";`

Comment: did you got back errors?

Comment: Is `$con->query` return `true` or `false? Have you checked for errors, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php?

Comment: Very strange.Are you sure the transaction is being committed? Is "auto_commit" disabled ? Are you sure that PHP is connecting to the same database ? How are you sure that assignment is working ? Have you tried setting it to a different value, like 420 ? (All of the other things I can thing of, the datatype of STOCK_Cost column, BEFORE UPDATE triggers, etc. would all affect MySQL Workbench. Kudos for running tests from a different client. If it's not something goofy, like connecting to a different database, it has me stumped. (There's nothing "special" about a plus sign in a php string.)

Comment: At this point, I'm mostly suspicious of the report that `SET STOCK_Cost = 9` query from PHP is actually working, and that the `9` you're seeing isn't from the test run in MySQL Workbench. I recommend you run a test that sets the value to something unique, and then check the results. (We're assuming that the `OpenDBConnection` function is performing the necessary checks to verify that the connection is valid.)

Comment: "normally I use variables for the different values." I'm wondering if you may have lost the part of your PHP code that's making this not work when you simplified it for clarity? I cannot reproduce this error.

Comment: That's the thing. Maybe my explanation was too detailed but I just wanted to make clear my functions are working correctly. I've tested again and again, but using the above functions in my PHP code:

Comment: the update part:   x=y works  directly in MySQL and the PHP functions described above. The   x=x+y  version works in MySQL but doesn't work in PHP. I'm not typing the sql statement, I'm copy-pasting it from my PHP editor. I've made sure case is correct. I've removed the decimal point from Y. But it doesn't work from PHP.

Comment: And yes I've tried different values. The OpenDBConnection is working all over the place in my script. I've simplified the text not just for clarity on stackoverflow, but in the actual script itself, removing variables that create the string.

Comment: So, just to clarify again. In the above bit of code in my first message: changing "9" to "STOCK_Cost + 9", WITHOUT changing anything else, and it STOPS working my PHP script. But copy-pasting the exact same string from my PHP editor directly to MySQL Workbench, and the string does what it has to do.

Comment: chris85: I've changed the query bit to:         if($con->query($sql)){
            echo 'Query Executed';
            }      , and indeed, it only echoes "query executed" when it says STOCK_Cost = 9, but not when it says "STOCK_Cost = STOCK_Cost +9" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem ... for security reasons I'd given the user very restrictive permissions on fields in the table ... the following is the grant for the table:

```
GRANT SELECT (PO_ID, STOCK_ProductID), UPDATE (STOCK_Cost) ON  etc.
```

It should of course be the following for the query to work.

```
GRANT SELECT (PO_ID, STOCK_ProductID, STOCK_Cost), UPDATE (STOCK_Cost) ON  etc.
```

The user on MySQL Workbench was a different one from the one I'm using in the PHP script, so that's why it did work there.

Silly me ... I was going crazy about this ... thanks to all of you that tried to help me out.

Comment: Marcel, you should "accept" your own answer (by clicking the big checkmark). Although your problem was particular to your circumstances, it could happen to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that the PHP call is case sensitive?
Are you using `STOCK_Cost` and writing `"STOCK_Cost = STOCK_Cost + 9"` exactly as the column is declared in the table schema?

Comment: No it's not that. In the last paragraph of my question I typed the case wrong by mistake. But if you look at the actual code the case is correct (STOCK_Cost). As I've already mentioned, the query runs correctly directly in MYSQL, which is also case sensitive. I don't type the query but copy - paste it directly from the PHP editor I'm using.

Comment: What is the definition for the STOCK_Cost column, int(10) varchar(255) ?